# Why does Voila on Jupyter Notebook give a 403 error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, voila

I have a python notebook file that outputs an HTML file as a final output, but when I run voila, it gives off a 403 error. Tried to run it on binder, but same error. Is there any way around this?